# Intersection between register automata and pushdown automata over infinite alphabet

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages, automata-theory

I'm not an expert in automata theory, this is a reference request.
As far as I have understood it is known in the automata comunity that register automata by Kaminski are closed by intersection with pushdown automata over infinite alphabet.
Unfortunately I'm not able to find any reference about this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you might start by citing kaminsky register automata....

Comment: a reference I just found said register automata are "similar" to finite memory automata 1st studied by kaminsky [and francez] possibly in [this paper of the same name by kaminsky](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397594902429) or nearby

Comment: Maybe it is possible to do a product construction as in the case of intersecting DFA and PDA.